# Get picture direct url from picasa

Tags: api, picasa

i'm trying to display google.picasa.com pictures in my website (using PHP).

As input, i have a picasa web url, such as :

```
http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/view?q=landscape&psc=G&filter=1#5275236656640118898
```

or :

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/lACqXExH_Pz9OLsFkfgxmA
```

I need to get the image direct url to set it as the src attribute of an  tag.
I use regexp to extract the picture id, but i couldn't find how to get the direct url in google Picasa API...

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($insertedEntry->getMediaGroup()->getContent() != null) {
    $mediaContentArray = $insertedEntry->getMediaGroup()->getContent();
    $contentUrl = $mediaContentArray[0]->getUrl();
}

if ($insertedEntry->getMediaGroup()->getThumbnail() != null) {
    $mediaThumbnailArray = $insertedEntry->getMediaGroup()->getThumbnail();
    $firstThumbnailUrl = $mediaThumbnailArray[0]->getUrl();
}

echo "<img src='".$contentUrl."'  />";

echo "Content URL : " . $contentUrl . "<br />\n";
//echo "First Thumbnail: " . $firstThumbnailUrl . "<br />\n";

echo "<br />\n";
```